# Development environments offered from the cloud

Tags: development, visual-studio

Would cloud based development servers be a valid alternative for local development environments?
The cloud based dev environment might consist of a separate physical SQL server, and a SP dev image used to creating new dev environments quickly on the fly (for temporary developers, for example).
Has somebody tried this? How would the efficiency drop with more simultaneous developers? (I wonder if any charts exist for this etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's one of the purposes of [CloudShare](http://cloudshare.com/) you can use one of their standard environments of build your own and then share a snapshot of that with your developers

Comment: Cloudshare is fantastic, we use it for demos. It would even be cost effective to use it as standard dev box ($500/year/person).

Comment: Thanks. However, developing for many years with a large number of developers using CloudShare would become costly. Setting up an own cloud might work better in our scenario as we have most of the infrastructure in place already. Thus i'd ike to know more about the performance issues etc related to sp development. I wonder if CloudShare'd like to share that kinda info =)

Comment: Remember to include license costs for MSDN as well on a own setup

Comment: I suppose developers could use their own individual MSDN licenses for development.

Comment: Yes if they have them. Using CloudShare they provide the licenses. Just something you might consider when calculating the cost. But if it's for full time then a own solution os probably cheaper.